# using stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromFtring in shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation iOS Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

I am getting empty string when using `StringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString` that is reading a `javascript` function. I am using a `StringByEvalutaingJavascriptFromString` in `ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` because i want to control supported orientations on specific pages.

It seems that i need to use it `webViewDidFinishLoad`.
But how to control supported orientations on specific pages using `StringByEvalutaingJavascriptFromString`.
Or how to use it in ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation.

I followed this tutorial: [link](http://www.web-garden.co.uk/blog/2012/7/26/how-to-control-the-page-orientations-in-your-ios-phonegap-application)

and he is using it in `ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` and not in `webViewDidFinishLoad`

this is my code in MainViewController.m:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:   (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    NSString *isFirstPage = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:   @"isFirstPage();"];
    NSString *truth = @"true";
    if ([isFirstPage isEqualToString:truth]) {
        return [super shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
    }
    else {
        return interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
}
```

and isFirstPage is return a empty string @"".

```
function isFirstPage(){
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if troll question... or just a terrible API.

Comment: hi sorry for bad format, but i am new to objective c and phonegap